# How the series is converging?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(\alpha_j)$ be a sequence in upper half plane. Let $$S = \sum_j \frac{\Im{ \alpha_j}}{|\alpha_j + i|^2} $$ be a series. We want to show that $S$ converges if and only if
$$
\sum_{|\alpha_j| < 1} \operatorname{\Im}(\alpha_j) < \infty
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{|\alpha_j|\ge 1} \operatorname{\Im}\bigg( \frac1{\alpha_j} \bigg) < \infty, 
$$

I tried to write $$ S = \sum_{|\alpha_j| < 1} \frac{\Im{ \alpha_j}}{|\alpha_j + i|^2} + \sum_{|\alpha_j| \ge 1} \frac{\Im{ \alpha_j}}{|\alpha_j + i|^2}.$$

I can show that  if $S$ converges then $\sum_{|\alpha_j| < 1} \operatorname{\Im}(\alpha_j)$ converges by comparison test. But I do not know how to prove the other sum converges and how to prove the converse.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|\alpha_j+i|^{2}\leq 2|\alpha_j|^{2}$ an $\Im (\frac1  {\alpha_j})=-\frac {\Im \alpha_j} {|\alpha_j|^{2}}$.